# Desktop icon size editing with nautilus

Tags: nautilus

Icons on my desktop look very big even after setting the icon view defaults to 50% in nautilus preferences.

[image: Screenshot of Desktop]

[image: Screenshot of nautilus preferences]

Please help in fixing this issue?

Comment: Strange ... Did you try restart Nautilus?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @EricCarvalho I still have the same problem..I am not sure what else i need to add for this question.

Answer (score -1):

you can just **Right click** on icon and select **Resize Icon** option in popup window...

It will show u a dotted rectangle around icon, and then u can resize it to anyhow u want.

for more details, visit [resizing desktop icon](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-resize-desktop-icons-in-ubuntu-linux/)

Comment: Can you explain *how* to use CompizConfig Settings Manager to adjust the size of icons? Right now, this doesn't really answer the question...